# Jenkins Pipeline File - Passing Jenkinsfile variables into further commands

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-multibranch

**Issue:**

In passing a variable declared within Jenkinsfile to a `sh` command that ssh's and executes on a remote host, the variable contents are not retained on the remote host.

**Built-in Jenkins variables retain fine both locally and on the remote host. The variable I've defined works fine locally but doesn't translate on the remote host.**

Although this issue references Docker, this is actually 100% Jenkins pipeline-based as it could apply to any example with or without Docker.

**Background:**

I'm trying to dynamically create an image name based on the current build
tag and put that name into a variable.

Then I pass that variable into the `sh` step which remotes over to a Docker host and runs a build step with the name defined.

Snippet of applicable parts of Jenkinsfile...

```
// The below stage just echo's out some stuff into a file dockerimgname.jenkins.out
stage ('Construct Img name') {
  sh '''echo ${BUILD_TAG} | awk '{print tolower($0)}' | sed 's/jenkins-//' > dockerimgname.jenkins.out'''
}

// This stage reads that file from previous stage and puts the value into variable.
// The variable is echo'd locally which works perfectly. Then ssh is called to execute command on remote host. That's where the variable value doesn't work.
stage ('Build Target Container') {
  def jobBaseName = readFile 'dockerimgname.jenkins.out'
  echo "${jobBaseName}"
  sh 'ssh -i ~/ssh_keys/key.key user@somehost "cd /dockerdata/build/${BUILD_TAG} && docker build -t localrepo/${jobBaseName}:${BUILD_NUMBER} ."'
}
```

**Normally I would assume it doesn't have the variables since it's a remote host... However it is odd that `${BUILD_NUMBER}` and `${BUILD_TAG}` translate and work fine on the remote host. Why doesn't `${jobBaseName}`?? (it comes out empty/null on remote host).**

Comment: Are you sure that your shell command writes something meaningful to the `dockerimgname.jenkins.out` file?  Have you logged in to the executor node and verified this?

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes, I have verified it looks right in the file. I would rather not use a file at all but am having problems with the variable declaration being global between stages so the file was a workaround. Regardless, yes I've verified the file contents look good.

Comment: Are you sure it's not string interpolation inside single quotes? Try ```echo 'ssh -i ~/ssh_keys/key.key user@somehost "cd /dockerdata/build/${BUILD_TAG} && docker build -t localrepo/${jobBaseName}:${BUILD_NUMBER} ."'```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's not guaranteed that your individual stages will run on the same executor node (unless you have the stages wrapped up in the same `node` block), using files to share information between stages will be unreliable.  Instead use variables:

```
def jobBaseName

stage ('Construct Img name') {
  jobBaseName = sh(
    script: "echo ${BUILD_TAG} | awk '{print tolower($0)}' | sed 's/jenkins-//'",
    returnStdout: true,
  )
}

stage ('Build Target Container') {
  sh "ssh -i ~/ssh_keys/key.key user@somehost 'cd /dockerdata/build/${BUILD_TAG} && docker build -t localrepo/${jobBaseName}:${BUILD_NUMBER} .'"
}
```

By the way, I would also suggest using `sshAgent` and Jenkins' built-in credentials store to manage SSH keys instead of manually passing in the `-i` flag to SSH.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was having issues with the declared variable passing between stages. Since you're declaring it outside of the stages that may resolve it. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Jenkins is complaining about syntax with the above. `WorkflowScript: 10: unexpected token: echo` 

the `^` in the error log is pointing to the double quote `"` on the `script "echo` line

Comment: Pretty sure I just missed a colon.  Should be `script: "..."`.  Updated.

Comment: @jayhendren could you give a pointer to using Credentials and SSH in the intended way? I fell back on "withCredentials", that feels like a kludge...

Comment: @SamuelÅslund the instructions for using credentials with SSHAgent are [here in the official docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/).  You just need to supply the name of the credentials as an argument to `sshagent`, i.e. `sshagent(credentials: ['my-credentials-id']) { sh 'ssh myuser@myhost ...' }`.

Comment: @jayhendren Thanks, I missed that one in the noice. It does not document how to pull the username from the key tho, so I think I'll stay with "withCredentials" for now